# How do I use IF in MS Excel-Mac 2011 for 3 variables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2011

When I type A, B or 0 in one cell, I want to see in other two cells (separately) to show

```
2,1 if I type A
1,2 if I type B
0,0 if I type 0
```

Can someone help me how to do this?

I currently only have for A and B.
where the formula for A is: =if(B3=U2,2,1) 
and formula for B is: =if(B3=U2,1,2)

U2 cell has the letter B in it. So, I am not even sure if everything overall is even functioning correctly or is it just in the air. Looks like it is just in the air.

Answer (score 1):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1=0,0,IF(A1="A",2,1))
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=IF(A1=0,0,IF(A1="A",1,2))
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To cover the case in which the data cell does not contain either **A** or **B** or **0**, use these formulas in **B1** and **C1**:

```
=IF(A1=0,0,IF(A1="A",2,IF(A1="B",1,"")))    

=IF(A1=0,0,IF(A1="A",1,IF(A1="B",2,"")))
```

**EDIT#2:**

If you can *guarantee* that **A1** contains either **A** or **B** or **0**, then you don't need a complex ***If*** structure.  You can use:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,"A","B"},{0,2,1})
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,"A","B"},{0,1,2})
```

[image]

Comment: Although this answer will work if you type in A, B or 0, if you type anything else, it will still give 1,2 (as if B was entered) An extra `if` is required if you don't want this behavior.

Comment: @LPChip  You are correct!!

Comment: Yes, true. I typed in "a" where "s" is and it showed result: 1, 1.

Comment: @Tine  Do you want a "better" formula??

Comment: @Tine  See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: Sure. Yes, please :) (It was constantly saying 7 more to go... at the bottom of the window and I thought I am time limited but I see now I was insufficient in letters,lol)

Comment: Thank you Gary! This was awesome. I had to change the formula for my second cell though. In one it says: =IF(B3=0,0,IF(B3="B",2,IF(B3="S",1,""))) and in the other it says =IF(B3=0,0,IF(B3="B",1,IF(B3="S",2,""))) otherwise I get both values as 2 in both cells. I want to have one value as 2 and other as 1 when I type B and other way around when I type S. :) Nevertheless, without your help, I had nothing,hehe. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Tine  Glad to help!

Comment: Here is yet another variant `=IFERROR(MID("021";FIND(A1;"0AB");1);"")` - comparable to "EDIT2", but with error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Gary and Chip, you rock!
I found out that if I keep the formula the same for both cells then I get a different result (which is what I want). Why does this happen, I have no idea. hehe 
But thanks, I didn't know it is that simple, to just put A1=0,0, and then continue with IF[image]
B=b
and A=s

IF you have any suggestions, please feel free to update me, correct me. 
Thank you so much.